# Order by Date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Trying to order by as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_DATE(e.PUB_DATE_PRINT, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS "Publication Date"
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY e.PUB_DATE_PRINT DESC
```

I'm getting an error here because of the date, as there are some nulls in my e.PUB_DATE_PRINT column.

- If I change to TO_CHAR, I get duplicates (there are some joins in my full query)
- If I SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY TO_CHAR(e.PUB_DATE_PRINT, 'DD Mon YYYY'), I get the correct number of records, but I can't order it correctly, as it orders by the 'DD'

I can't seem to work this out...! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `TO_DATE(e.PUB_DATE_PRINT, 'DD Mon YYYY')` is nonsense if `PUB_DATE_PRINT` is already a `DATE`. Because using that expression `PUB_DATE_PRINT` will be first converted to a `varchar` (using implicit conversion rules) which will then be converted back to a `date` - which it was right from the start. If you only want to consider the date without time, use `trunc()`

Answer (score 0):

`Order by` is the last clause in the query to be applied, so it already has the final resultset to work on.

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_DATE(e.PUB_DATE_PRINT, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS "Publication Date"
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Hmm, no I'm getting the error message: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Comment: i believe that because that to_date is failing, is you PUB_DATE_PRINT blank?

Comment: Yep, I think you're right, there are some nulls in there. I tried converting by TO_CHAR but this returned the issue with the column ordering by 'DD'.